# Python - Preprocessing a lot of image data - Loop freezes

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have the following code in my Python Script:

```
def process_data(data):
    features = []

    for i in range(int(len(data))): # Should iterate 33'000 times (length of data)
        for j in range(3):
            img = plt.imread(data[i][j].strip()) # Data is from a csv file
            img = normalize(img)  # Simple calculation

            lis = img.flatten().tolist()
            features += lis

return features
```

This should run for about 33'000*3 times to preprocess the whole data. However, after around 10'000-12'000 iterations, the script slows down radically, freezes and sometimes my machine (i7 - 3.6GHz, 8GB RAM) freezes as well.

What can I do? It's difficult to split up the data. I was told to use the Keras' `fit_generator` before but how would I do that?

Comment: why do you want to put this in a python list? It's far efficient to store it in 1D numpy array. Also could you please give more info about how `data` look like?

Comment: And please never use `range(len(..))`. A better option is `enumerate(..)`

Comment: @kmario23 I will use enumerate, thanks :) It is? Okay, I will store it in a 1D Numpy array then. Data consists of 3 images (rgb values) and a value between 0-50.. So something like [[[255,255,255],[255,255,255], ..],[[255,255,255],[255,255,255], ..],[[255,255,255],[255,255,255], ..],10.5]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly. Please update your question providing more info about `data` and the `csv` file. It's very hard to understand what you mean. For an 8gb machine, this is nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large those image files are, you could be running out of RAM and being forced to swap. That would cause your system to be sluggish.
Instead of gathering all the processed files into list, can you write them out one at a time?

Comment: Hm, difficult. I need to split the data after that (factor 1:4) and then save it into a [pickled file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Any idea on how I could solve this?